# Button_Click() doesnt fire with $().ready /function pageLoad()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This might be a silly question ..I m New to Client Side technology.. But i just wanted to know .. does Button_Click() wont Fire with $().ready function simply ?...

this is my Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script runat="server">

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


        $().ready(){ alert(' '); }

      ----another try 
      $(document).ready()

      ---another try 

    function pageLoad() { alert(' '); }


     --another try 
     $(document).ready(function() { 
     alert("Document is Ready Now!");
     });


        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"    
/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested it on FireBug ..$().ready wont fire before or After Button_Click() ..DO i Need to use Script Manager.. I have seen some suggestion ..
I Couldnt able to find something relevant ..PLease Suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(document).ready()`

This function will be executed before any other function in script.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery document ready statement like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Document is Ready Now!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this ....kindly check have attach jquery library in your project or not.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Button1').click(function(){
    alert("Document is Ready Now!");
    });
});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GYTPZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

why you use bellow code when use jquery use the second code

```
<script runat="server">

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    </script>




     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Button1').click(function(){
        alert("this is alert!");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the jQuery CDN that you're using.

Hit this link http://code.jquery.com/Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js. It will show up a `404 Not Found` error.

Try other CDN's.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

I think you've got the wrong path to the jquery.

It should be

`http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js` and not `http://code.jquery.com/Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js`. Observe the difference.

The link point to `Javascript` directory which doesn't exist